# Wrong URI after Form Submit MVC 3 asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I'm a little confused on something here. I have a form, and the URL for that form is:

```
http://domain.com/Home/requestquote
```

When I click submit on a form and the method handling this form located in the form controller sends back a view, the URI looks like this:

`http://domain.com/form/requestQuoteSubmit` where `requestQuoteSubmit` is the method.

This occurs both when validation sends the page back for errors and when there is a successful form submit.

On success the view being sent back is `Home/thanks` and on error it should just send back `Home/requestquote`. Everything seems to work fine except for the fact that the URI is not what it is supposed to be. This causes everything else on the page to break because my links look like this:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(Model.CompanyPageDatabaseModel.companyCode, new { Controller = MVC.services.Name, Action = MVC.services.ActionNames.page })
```

So that companyCode value isn't being passed around properly and forming the links correctly. I'm not sure how or why the form method is sending back the correct page, but setting the URI to itself?

Here are my routes.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{action}",
            new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index },
            new { RootAction = new RootActionConstraint() }  // Route Constraint
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null, // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index }, // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = "Home|contact|franchise|form|resources|services|technology|community|careers|carriers|about" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           null,
           "{companyCode}/{action}",
           new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index },
           new { RootAction = new RootActionConstraint() }  // Route Constraint
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "jax",
            "{companyCode}/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.Index }
        );
```

The last route value is an example of a franchisee route.

Also here is the form code in the view:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("requestquote", "form", FormMethod.Post))
    {   }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: Added in my routes.

Comment: can you share the code for your action method "requestQuoteSubmit"

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept referred to as PRG, which stands for **Post-Redirect-Get**.

The basic idea is that you **Post** the form to your application.  After processing the input, you then **Redirect** to a **Get** request at the correct URL, instead of serving the user a content response directly from the submission.

This is good for many reasons, but the underlying one is separation of concerns.  (When you don't separate concerns weird stuff like all the links might breaking on your page tends to happen...)

So, the solution for you is to process the submission, and if invalid, store your Validation content in `TempData` and return a `RedirectToRouteResult(controller:"Home",action:"RequestQuote")`

**Update:** I found the original article I read to learn this concept.  It's in terms of the original ASP.NET MVC release, but it should be mostly the same.  Check out http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Using-Post2c-Redirect2c-Get-Pattern.aspx

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong here. Here's what I'm trying right now:

            routes.MapRoute(
                "requestquote", 
                "{action}", 
                new { controller = MVC.Home.Name, action = MVC.Home.ActionNames.requestquote }           
            );

And then my controller is returning:
return RedirectToRoute("requestquote");

Is the tempdata needed to get the correct URI? My uri when using this is domain.com/requestQuoteSubmit which of course it can't find.

Comment: Post your full routing declaration in order.  It sounds like your declarations may be sending everything to the requestquote action because of its pattern and precedence.

Comment: Edited my post up top to include it. Also added in the form code in the view.

Comment: @Nozoku, I think we'll need to see what that `RootActionConstraint` does as well as the Controller actions